# How to send HTTP POST request using Substrate Offchain worker

Tags: substrate-node-template, offchain-worker, offchain

I am using Substrate official example to send HTTP POST request, which is mentioned here https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/offchain-workers/offchain-http-requests/#read-and-submit-the-response

```
// Send a POST request
  let deadline = sp_io::offchain::timestamp().add(Duration::from_millis(3_000));
let request_body = Vec::new();
let request = http::Request::post("https://reqres.in/api/users", vec![request_body.clone()])
 .add_header("x-api-key", "test_api_key")
 .add_header("content-type", "application/json");

let pending = request
 .deadline(deadline)
 .body(vec![request_body.clone()])
 .send()
 .map_err(|_| http::Error::IoError)?;

// Wait for response
let response = pending
 .try_wait(deadline)
 .map_err(|_| http::Error::DeadlineReached)??;
```

But Its not working. I am getting `fetch_response error: Error::IoError`

I am able to execute sample HTTP Get request but not able to execute above POST request.

Can somebody please help me to fix this?

Comment: Can you try to log the error on the `.map_err` line?